# SQL Server 2008: what happened if identity oversteps a maximal value of int?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, identity-management

Imagine we have a table:

```
create table MYTABLE (
 id int IDENTITY(1,1)
,name varchar(10)
)
```

We have to insert a lot of rows into the table.

Does anybody know what will happen when a generated identity  value oversteps a maximal integer value (2^32-1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You will get the following error:

   `Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 1`
   `Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int.`
   `Arithmetic overflow occurred.`
2. You won't be able to insert more records, until you:

   - delete some and reset the identity column using [the `DBCC CHECKIDENT` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx),
     **or**
   - change column's data type to `bigint` (suggested by [Gabriel Guimarães](https://serverfault.com/users/56298/)).

Comment: or alter the column to bigint?

Comment: or decimal (20,0)?

Comment: You can also reseed the identity to a large, negative number, in a pinch.